# Is there a list of multilingual rhymes?

Tags: multilingualism, words

I'm searching for multilingual rhymes like:

```
Star - far / Stern - fern (German)
```

Unfortunately I only have this one so far.

Comment: Well, this is bound to be a very broad question. The list is potentially infinite. Unfortunately I can't think of a way to improve it.

Comment: Do you mean sets of word-pairs where the pairs rhyme within a single language, and the words have roughly the same two meanings across the languages?

Comment: Of course such rhymes should be common because if two languages are related (like English and German), the respective words may differ only by regular sound changes (like dropping the final -n). Additionally there is a lot of international words borrowed between languages.

Comment: @user6726: exactly